# An ambiguous word for a place one travels through

Tags: word-choice

Is there a word in English language or a even another language that communicates: "this is a place you travel through"

Asking for a friend.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're looking for. I don't think you mean that you think there's one word whose meaning is the same as that of the whole sentence, "This is a place you travel through." And I can't think of a context in which one would use that sentence.

Comment: "whistle-stop" -

Comment: a don't stop place

Answer (score 1):

While technically two words, ***way station*** might work:

> [Oxford US English Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/way_station):
>
>   A stopping point on a journey.
>   *‘the hotel was a way station for all the aid workers
>     who passed through the city’*
>
> [Collins English Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/way-station):
>
> 1. A **way station** is a place
>      where people stop to eat and rest when they are on a long trip.
>
>    A **way station** is a small station
>      between two large stations on a railroad.
>
> [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/way%20station):
>
> 1. a station set between principal stations on a line of travel
>      (such as a railroad)
>
>    an intermediate stopping place
>
> [the Cambridge English Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/way-station):
>
>   a place where people can stop when travelling
>     from one place to another

i.e., you might stop there temporarily, but it’s not a destination.

Answer (score 0):

In aviation, a "waypoint" is a place along the flight path used for verifying your position. You do not stop; but, continue on past it.